# Why wont my fetch request data appear in my app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a React-Redux app with a Rails API. I'm making a fetch request via my reviewsFetch action, which is working properly and appearing in my console. However, I'm trying to build out the ReviewList file and the ReviewCard file and I want my fetch data to appear on the page (an example JSON data reads as data.review.attributes.title) i'm getting a lot of undefined errors.

As it stands currently, 'props' in my const ReviewList is undefined and I'm pretty sure 'reviews' is also and I can't figure out why.

/actions/reviewsFetch.js

```
export const getReviews = reviews => {
    return {
        type: "GET_REVIEWS",
        reviews
    }
} //action creator


export const reviewsFetch = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/reviews', {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(reviews => dispatch (getReviews(reviews.data)))
    }
}
```

/reducers/reviewReducer.js

```
export default function reviewReducer (state = {reviews: [], comments: []}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_REVIEWS":
            return {...state, reviews: action.reviews}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

/containers/ReviewsContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reviewsFetch } from "../actions/reviewsFetch.js";
//import ReviewCard from "../components/reviews/Reviews";


class ReviewsContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.reviewsFetch();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reviews: state.reviews
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { reviewsFetch }
)(ReviewsContainer);
```

/components/MainContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReviewList from './reviews/ReviewList'

const MainContainer = () => {
    return (
        <div className="MainContainer">
            <ReviewList />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainContainer
```

/components/reviews/ReviewList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReviewCard from './ReviewCard'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const ReviewList = props => {
    const reviewCards = props.reviews.map(r => <ReviewCard review={r}/>)
  return (
      reviewCards.length > 0 ? reviewCards : null
  )
}
//mapstatetoprops tells redux to provide access to its state
//so we may pick and choose the pieces of state we would like available
//to this particular component as props
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reviews: state.reviews
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReviewList)
```

/components/reviews/ReviewCard.js

```
import React from 'react'

const ReviewCard = ({ review }) => {
  return (
    <p>{review.data.attributes.title}</p>
  )
}

export default ReviewCard
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import reviewsFetch from "./actions/reviewsFetch.js"
import ReviewsContainer from './containers/ReviewsContainer';
import ReviewList from './components/reviews/ReviewList'
//import ReviewCard from './components/reviews/ReviewCard'

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //this.props.reviewsFetch()
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img className="App-logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/fXg9HgB/2-22657-smiley-face-black-and-white-smiley-face-clipart.png" alt="spite-house-smiley"/>
      
      <br></br>
      <ReviewsContainer />
      <ReviewList />
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import store from './store.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reviewReducer from './reducers/reviewReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    reviewReducer
  })
  
  const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

  export default store
```

Answer (score 0):

When a fetch data using an HTTP request, it wont be available on the initial render. You have to wait for it to resolve.

You can add a check in your component as following :

```
const reviewCards = props?.reviews?.map?.(r => <ReviewCard review={r}/>)
```

The above approach is using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

or you can have conditional check whether to see if the data has been fetched successfully or not and toggle a loading state.

Comment: Thank you for this. This just returns another error that says Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. any idea why that is?

Comment: Just do 'reviewCards?.length' as thats also will depend upon when your request resolves.